# How to set different hover color for each link

Tags: html, css

I have the following DIV:

```
<div id="second-menu-navi" class="navi">
            <a href="" id="tab-1">Why Choose Us</a>
            <a href="" id="tab-2">Physicians</a>
            <a href="" id="tab-3">Medical Specialties</a>
            <a href="" id="tab-4">Locations</a>
            <a href="" id="tab-5">Urgent Care</a>
            <a href="" id="tab-6">Radiology</a>
            <a href="" id="tab-7">Lab</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS which changes the background color when hovered over:

```
#second-menu-navi a:hover, #second-menu-navi a.active {
    background-color:#155E9B;
}
```

I was trying to change each tab to have a different hover color by adding the following CSS:

```
#second-menu-navi #tab-1 a.active, #second-menu-navi #tab-1 a.hover {
    background-color: #155E9B;
}
#tab-2 a.active, #tab-2 a.hover {
    background-color: #159B77;
}
#tab-3 a.active, #tab-3 a.hover {
    background-color: #1E9B15;
}
#tab-4 a.active, #tab-4 a.hover {
    background-color: #969B15;
}
#tab-5 a.active, #tab-5 a.hover {
    background-color: #9B2B15;
}
#tab-6 a.active, #tab-6 a.hover {
    background-color: #9B1574;
}
#tab-7 a.active, #tab-7 a.hover {
    background-color: #70159B;
}
```

But none of the link changes background color when hovered. Please help me fix the issue.

Comment: Can you put this into a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/erenyener/j7pEx/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way you can change the color for each link on mouse hover. Here is the working **[Demo.](http://jsbin.com/saqepeya/1/)**

```
a#tab-1:hover {
    color:aqua;
}
a#tab-2:hover {
    color:red;
}
a#tab-3:hover {
    color:green;
}
a#tab-4:hover {
    color:gray;
}
a#tab-5:hover {
    color:yellow;
}
a#tab-6:hover {
    color:gold;
}
a#tab-7:hover {
    color:blue;
}
```

you can make a background image transparent. Here is the **[Demo.](http://jsbin.com/bakefune/1/)**

```
#container {
   position: relative;
}
#container:after {
    content : "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/300); 
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    opacity : 0.5;
-moz-opacity:0.5;
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=40)"; /*IE8*/
}
```

If using RGBA property. all modern browser supported it. However to work in IE8 or lower its required to use `filter`.

```
/* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000);
    /* For IE 8*/
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";
```

Comment: Is background image opacity solution work in your case?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge here is the workaround to make the background image transparent.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge let me know if my solution works in your case.

Comment: IF this solves your problem please close this by accepting the answer.

Comment: Please explain your answer to make it better.

Comment: My opacity for RGBA is `.85` so what will it be for the first two number after the `#` for IE <= 8?

Answer (score 5):

In principle, for using pseudo-selectors, change the periods to colons:

```
a.hover
```

becomes:

```
a:hover
```

See more information about `:hover` on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ahover).

For your problem, you need to apply the `:hover` directly to the `#tab-1`, rather than the `a`. So:

`#tab-1 a.hover`

becomes:

`#tab-1:hover` or `a#tab-1:hover`.

Answer (score 3):

You are selecting an `<a>` child of `#tab-2`, as well as using the wrong pseudo-selector.

Instead of `#tab-2 a.hover` use `a#tab-2:hover`.

Instead of `#tab-2 a.active`, use `a#tab-2:active`.

Answer (score 2):

Not `#tab-7 a.hover`, its not correct. Use this `#tab-7:hover`

OR

`#tab-7.active`

Comment: This did the trick. My background for the tabs are an color image with opacity 85%. When I hover over for the color they also have an opacity. Is there anyway to have a background image with an opacity and when hovered, the color is solid?

Comment: instead of using opacity you can use Css style `background:rgba()`  it would be helpful to play with it..

Comment: @KheemaPandey WORKS great in FF/Chrome/IE10 but does not work in IE8 :/ Any workaround you know of?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge I've shared my example with you.. please check my answer.

Comment: As rgba doesn't supported by IE8 you can use filters for IE8.

`/* For IE 8*/
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";
`

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR;**

**DEMO:** [CodePen](http://codepen.io/ryanw/pen/Ffdyw/)

You want to use the [CSS Pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pseudo-classes): `:hover`

```
a#tab-2:active,
a#tab-2:hover {
    background-color: #159B77;
}
```

There are good resources out there for things like this.

---

## [Pseudo classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pseudo-classes) on MDN:

> A CSS ***pseudo-class*** is a keyword added to selectors that
>   specifies a special state of the element to be selected. For example
>   [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ahover) will
>   apply a style when the user hovers over the element specified by the
>   selector.
>
> Pseudo-classes, together with pseudo-elements, let you apply a style
>   to an element not only in relation to the content of the document
>   tree, but also in relation to external factors like the history of the
>   navigator
>   ([:visited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3avisited),
>   for example), the status of its content (like
>   [:checked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3achecked)
>   on some form elements), or the position of the mouse (like
>   [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ahover)
>   which lets you know if the mouse is over an element or not).

### Syntax:

```
selector:pseudo-class {
  property: value;
}
```

So in your case, it would be:

```
a#tab-2:active,
a#tab-2:hover {
    background-color: #159B77;
}
```

---

## More on [**:hover**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ahover) from MDN:

> The :hover CSS pseudo-class matches when the user designates an
>   element with a pointing device, but does not necessarily activate it.
>   This style may be overridden by any other link-related pseudo-classes,
>   that is
>   [:link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alink),
>   [:visited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3avisited),
>   and
>   [:active](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3aactive),
>   appearing in subsequent rules. In order to style appropriately links,
>   you need to put the :hover rule after the :link and :visited rules but
>   before the :active one, as defined by the *LVHA-order*: :link —
>   :visited — :hover — :active.
>
> Visual user agents, like Firefox, Internet Explorer, Safari, Opera or
>   Chrome, apply the associated style when the cursor (mouse pointer)
>   hovers over an element.